# tooltip in JQX grid

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets, jqxtreegrid, jqxtree

I have a jqx grid, i have already enabled the tooltips for all the columns in the grid. one of the column in the grid will have images . how can i show text value in the tooltips

Please find the sample code

```
columns: [
                {
                    text: '',
                    dataField: 'valid',
                    width: '4%',
                    hidden: false,
                    editable: false,
                    enabletooltips:true,
                    filterable: false,
                    cellsrenderer: statusCellRenderer,
                    rendered: tooltipRenderer
                },
```

functions of the column :

```
   var statusCellRenderer = function(row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties, rowData) {
    console.log("row---------------->",this.uielement);
    //console.log("value---------->",value);
    //value =   false;
    //console.log("element------------>",element);
    if (rowData.errorMessage != ''){
        this.uielement.jqxTooltip({disabled:false,position: 'mouse', content: 'testing' });
        return '<div class="errorIcon">&#x26a0;</div>';
    }
    else
        return '';
}

var tooltipRenderer =   function(element) {
    $(element).jqxTooltip({disabled:false,position: 'mouse', content: 'testing' });
    element.textContent =   'Test';
    console.log("element------>",element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#grid').jqxGrid({
    cellhover: function (element, pageX, pageY, record) {
              var cellValue = $(element.innerHTML).find('span').html(); // you can remove if any element not required in tooltip here
              var tooltipContent = "<div>" + cellValue + "</div>";
              if (cellValue && cellValue.trim().length > 0) {
                $(element).jqxTooltip({ content: tooltipContent });
                $(element).jqxTooltip('open', pageX + 15, pageY + 15);
              } else {
                $('#grid').jqxTooltip('close');
              }           
          }
});
```

As you said this snippet will show tooltip for your entire grid cell. I hope this will help you. If you have any queries let me know.